# Prolog and sibling relationship?

Tags: prolog

I'm new to Prolog and having a bit of difficulty. I have:

```
man(ken).
man(tom).
woman(juli).

father(ken, tom).
father(ken, juli).

male(A) :- man(A).
brother(A,B) :- male(A), father(C,A), father(C,B), (A \= B).
```

I know the male/man is redundant, but it's part of the assignment. Anyway, when I try something like:

```
|?- brother(tom, juli).
```

I get "no" as the response. I'm sure I've made a stupid, simple mistake, but my lack of understanding is making it very hard to find. Can anyone see what my problem is?

Comment: I don't think you just got "no". You probably got a "true" then when asking for more results (you enter `;`) got a "no" since there weren't any more. That is a correct response.

Comment: That is what I did... so true means there was a match? So... it works?

Comment: Yes, true = success. :)

Comment: Oh lame... My teacher didn't go over how to use the enviornment at all... I can't believe it was such a simple mistake. If you want to answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: No worries. A lot of new prolog users are initially led astray by the response until they know what it means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you enter:

```
|?- brother(tom, juli).
```

You'll see a response something like this (SWI Prolog):

```
true ? ;

no
| ?-
```

So it first responds with "true" (gives a match) and then, after you enter `;` to show more solutions, it says "no" to indicate there are no further solutions. Some prolog interpreters may say "no" or "false" in this case, with the same meaning. This response from the prolog interpreters initially throws many a new prolog user.

You could, alternatively, press "enter" which just means you're done and don't want to see any further solutions:

```
true ?

yes
| ?-
```

Then you get "yes".